# Remove p tag from ckeditor5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

how to remove auto paragraph from ckeditor5.

for eg.

input =>  "this is body" in the text area
output => `<p>this is body</p>`

```
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector("#editor"), {
  autoParagraph: false,
  enterMode: 2
})
  .then((newEditor) => {
    editor = newEditor;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

i have tried to disabled autoParagraph and enterMode

Answer (score 0):

maybe this [Elegant way to change view schema in CKEditor5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53899331/elegant-way-to-change-view-schema-in-ckeditor5/54094675#54094675) can help you, that change `strong` to `b`